Don’t show the “Get updates on questions…” following post popup for suspended users
While being suspended, my reputation showed 1. Maybe the system thinks that I’m really a new user (user with less than 15 reputation), so the “Get updates on questions and answers…” shows again on this site for me.



But… suspended users can’t even follow or unfollow posts, so the notification is just nonsense for me and I need to dismiss the notification two/three times until the notifications won’t be shown on this site anymore.
So, I am curious: Why do we even need the “Get updates on…” notification for suspended users?
Noted that this question is definitely not the same as my question, (for me) I don’t need to dismiss the following prompt when I get the 15 reputation on this site.


""Why do we even need the “Get updates on…”" notification for suspended users?" Probably because whatever triggers that bit to show up doesn't know anything about suspended users. You probably found an edge case nobody thought or cared enough about.
